# Using Coordinates to find a tile in a grid

Tags: java, grid, coordinates

Im trying to work out how to take the x and y of a object and find what tile in a grid it is in.
So fare i got this:

```
public class testingcode {

public static void main(String[] args){

    //tiles are 32x32
    final int tilesX = 320;//grid size
    final int tilesY = 160;//grid size

    double charx = 220.20;
    double chary = 150.09;

    int tilenumber = 0;

    System.out.println("x is at tile number: "+ ((int)(charx/32)) + " out of 0-9");     

    System.out.println("y is at tile number: "+ ((int)(chary/32)) + " out of 0-4");     

    tilenumber = not a sausage

    System.out.println("tile on grid is: " + tilenumber);
}
```

}

removing the "tilenumber = not a sausage" will tell me that x is on the 6th grid across and y is on the 4th down(both starting from 0).

Using my brain i know these coords are in the 46th tile in the grid like so:

[image]

But i have no idea on how to turn 6 and 4 into 46 and my google's have got me know were so my question is: How do i get the tile number from these coordiantes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you look for:

```
tile = (10 * y) + x
```

??